# pcolormesh with user-defined value level

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

When I use plt.pcolormesh(xx,cmap =xx), I can't set the minimum value for plotting.

For example, I draw a 2-D array data which presents the population density of some area.

If I want to show the population density which exceed to some value(like 4500 people/Km2), I can use plt.contourf(pop,levels = [4500,6000,xxxx,xxxxx]) to solve that.

But I want to use pcolormesh style, I have thought about two methods:

- 1. set the colormap begin with "white".
- 2. set the user-defined levels like contourf plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two most obvious choices to me are (1) convert the data to a masked array and set the color using the `set_bad()` method of the colormap or (2) use the `vmin` argument to `pcolormesh()` and set the color using the `set_under()` method of the colormap.

Here's an example using some data in a Numpy array, `xx`, that have values between 0 and 57.  I've masked values less than 25 and set the plot color to black for the masked values just so it's easier to see the effect.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

F, (A1,A2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(15,5))

# Option 1:
xxm = np.ma.masked_less(x,25)

cmap1 = cm.get_cmap("jet",lut=10)
cmap1.set_bad("k")

A1.set_title("Using masked array")
P = A1.pcolormesh(LON,LAT,xxm,cmap=cmap1)
plt.colorbar(P,ax=A1)

# Option 2:
cmap2 = cm.get_cmap("jet",lut=10)
cmap2.set_under("k")

A2.set_title("Using vmin")
P = A2.pcolormesh(LON,LAT,xx,cmap=cmap2,vmin=25)
plt.colorbar(P,ax=A2)

plt.show()
```

[image]